# Alfred to run apps from Chrome App Launcher

Tags: macos, google-chrome, alfred

Chrome lately added Chrome App Launcher to the dock, in order to lunch installed chrome apps.

Can I create Alfred workflow in order to run them through Alfred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

They are stored in `~/Applications/Chrome Apps` (where `~` is your user's home folder), so you can add them to a workflow action like 'Launch Apps/Files'.

The easiest way though to add an app to the 'Launch Apps/Files' is to search for it in Alfred and drag the Alfred result into the 'Launch Apps/Files' list.

If the Chrome App doesn't show in Alfred results at all, add `~/Applications/Chrome Apps` to the 'Search Scope' in Preferences > Features > Default Results.

Comment: Once I found that folder I found out that there are only two chrome apps in it. Others, which aren't can be used as link like `chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, so it did solve my issue, thank you.

Comment: This is not enough for web extension that are just links. I see them in Chrome App Launcher, but there is nothing in ~/Applications/Chrome Apps

Comment: @uthark: If they're just links, you could just use the 'Open URL' action in an Alfred Workflow.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that whenever the version of the Chrome app is updated, the "add `~/Applications/Chrome Apps` to 'Search Scope'" strategy stops working. I solve this be rebuilding the OS metadata like so (button is grayed out because I just did this recently):

[image]